# Вопрос про cron задачу

Tags: cron

Здравствуйте, я никогда не имел дело с cron, и сейчас возникла необходимость использовать его.

У меня есть VPS, на ней установлен Centos 7. Мне нужно чтобы каждые допустим 12 часов, в папку `/home/www/site/index.php` поступал `$_GET['query']`.

Как можно это реализовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

добавить в крон такую строку

```
0 0,12 * * *  /usr/bin/curl --silent http://example.come/index.php?query=... &>/dev/null
```

либо вызывать php напрямую. Но тут могут быть "особенности" - не то окружение, неверный пользователь... Лучше, если Вы напишите готовый bash файл, который делает все нужное и его просто вызывать кроном.